# Selecting components for high current backup switch

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, multiplexer, backup

Does anyone have any pointers or tips on how I can select the correct PNP transistors and resistors for the following circuit?

If I need to drive up to 1.5A do I need MOSFETS instead of transistors?

Thanks

[image: backup curcuit]

Comment: *MOSFETS instead of transistors?* The T in mosfe**T** stands for **transistor**. You can use PNPs (Bipolar transistors) or MOSFETs if you like. I would probably use P-channel MOSFETs with a **low threshold voltage** as your supply is only 3 V.

Comment: Thanks yes poor choice of words I meant to say PNP. I will have a look into some low threshold MOSFETs.

Comment: Generally there are better MOSFETs available than bipolars. You get voltage gate drive and low Rdson (for the correct devices). I'd suggest MOSFETs unless there is a very specific reason not to.